# Wait for a task to finish in cucumber feature file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have been writing the cucumber tests for the application developed in Ruby on Rails. The application provisions a server (vm) and wait for the result (like success or fail) And displays the result. There are 7-8 different cases (or scenarios) for provisioning a server.

I have 2 questions

- How can I club these 2 different scenario outlines in to one. So that I don't need to repeat the table in Examples section. I wanted to create a provsioning requests for all scenarios (Examples) and then wait for 15 min till all requests gets provisioned and after 15 min check if all scenarios are passed or failed.
- As these tests take more time to complete, how can I skip them when I run "bundle cucumber" which runs all the feature files. I
  don't want to run the following test every time.

I have written cucumber tests by using scenario outline and examples as below .

```
Scenario Outline: Create A New Server Request
Given user is on create new server request page
When user enters follwing data

| Datacenter             | <Datacenter> |
| Cores          |<Cores>   |                                                   |
| Memory             | <Memory> |               

Then he should see request submitted


Examples: 
|DataCenter |Cores| Memory|
| ABC       | 2   | 1 GB  |
| DEF       | 4   | 2 GB  |
| GHI       | 8   | 4 GB  |
| JKL       | 4   | 2 GB  |


Scenario: Wait till provisioning happens
Given user waits for 15 minutes

Scenario Outline: Verify a New Server Request
Given user is on provision server  page
When user check the request with follwing data

| Datacenter             | <Datacenter> |
| Cores          |<Cores>   |                                                   |
| Memory             | <Memory> |               

Then he should see servers are provisioned

Examples: 
|DataCenter |Cores| Memory|
| ABC       | 2   | 1 GB  |
| DEF       | 4   | 2 GB  |
| GHI       | 8   | 4 GB  |
| JKL       | 4   | 2 GB  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anupam, I believe the Background holds the key to what you need. Set up your set of servers to work with as a variable using background and then simply refer to those during your scenario. I would also combine the "given the user is on ____ page" since you could bury that implementation detail in your stepdef to provision, check the queue and check the result.

```
Background: The set of servers to provision
Given the following set of servers are to be provisioned
|DataCenter |Cores| Memory|
| ABC       | 2   | 1 GB  |
| DEF       | 4   | 2 GB  |
| GHI       | 8   | 4 GB  |
| JKL       | 4   | 2 GB  |

@slow
Scenario: Provision New Servers
When a user provisions the set of servers
Then the user should see the set of servers submitted
When the user waits 15 minutes
Then the user should see the set of servers have been provisioned
```

To persist the background data across your steps, simply set it to a instance variable on your World object. I would probably use Cucumber::Ast::Table.hashes to get the data into an easier to use data format.

```
@server_set = table.hashes
```

As for not running these tests every time, I would set up a cucumber @tag which you use to exclude scenarios that take too long. You can also set up a yaml configuration file to handle this and then just call the appropriate profile in your tests. See the cucumber documentation for examples. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml

Edit: You could also set up the varioable on your first step def, but I like using background for "data" that you don't want to repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff for the suggestion. One more question how to extract the  table (with more than 2 columns ) rows in the step definition file? The example in the question uses the Cucumber::Ast::Table. And it gets passed to the step definition.

Comment: Added! Simply use an instance variable (which will be on your World object) and table.hashes. That should make you an array of hashes which you can get values for the keys of datacenter, cores and memory